# Handling dataset null values for both scenarios in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset

I have a `dataset` which will return 2 tables ie. `Table` and `Table1`. Now what I want is, sometime `Table` will be null and sometime `Table1` will be null. SO I want to handle both the conditions. Also there will be one more scenario where both the Tables will have data.

> After handling, I want to assign to string JSON

Here is my code

```
 public JsonResult GetSPanInfoByFTTX_FE_NEW(string FSA_ID)
    {
        string strJsonData = "";
        try
        {
            CTManagement objCT = new CTManagement();
            DataSet ds = objCT.GetSPanInfo_FTTX_FE(FSA_ID); // here I want to handle it
            strJsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds, Formatting.None);
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ErrorLog.HandleErrorLog("", "", "yy", e.Message);
            ApplicationLog.Error("Error", "yy", e.Message);
        }

        return Json(strJsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**Note**

This is how my dataset looks:

Scenario 1

`'{"Table":[],"Table1":[{"FSA_ID":"GWLR0115","AR_LENGTH":0.0}]}'`

Scenario 2

`'{"Table":[{"FSA_ID":"GWLR0115","UG_LENGTH":0.0}],"Table1":[]}'`

Comment: Please provide more details on what exactly should happen if one, the other or both are `null`? It's currently at least to me not clear what's actually supposed to happen.

Comment: @Mushroomator: The scenario is like this : At one time, either one table will be null or there will be data in both..

Comment: Yes I got that, but what should happen when either one is `null`? Should you log that, return (what to return?), throw (which exception?) or whatever other error handling? Am I right in assuming `DataSet` has two (nullable) properties called `Table` and `Table1`. It would help if you also posted what `DataSet` looks like.

Comment: @Mushroomator: If anyone is null then assign the default values as `0` to the columns in that table. Also will post what my dataset is looking

Comment: Have you tried passing `JsonSerializerSettings` in `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` wherein the `NullValueHandling` is set to `NullValueHandling.Ignore`?

Comment: @akg179: how to pass that ? please let me know

Comment: are both tables always returned, but each would have a row count of 0, or is the issue that 0, 1, or 2 tables are returned? If the 2nd case, then next question is the table name set and given a name? if yes, then you can find/match on the tables collection for the 2 table names, and take action based on that fact.  You can even use "contains" to check for the table name. So, if ds.tables.contains("table1") = false then table 1 is missing, and then ds.tables.contains("table2") = false, then table2 is missing. So, you can easy cover all cases this way.

Comment: @hud something like this `strJsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });`

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal: Hi Albert, yes both tables are always returned but each would have a row count of 0. so how canwe handle this ?

Comment: @akg179: the problem is even if it goes in any of tables, it is returning only one string, and that is the catch

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal: Also, if possible for the 2nd case, can u write a piece of code so that I can understand ?

Comment: @Mushroomator: I have updated the question for reference. Please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach can be this:

```
        if (ds.Tables.Contains("Table1"))
        {
            // do whatever for table 1
        }

        if (ds.Tables.Contains("Table2"))
        {
            // do whatever for table 2
        }
```

So, we might have 0, 1, 2 or only the 1st table, but not 2nd table. Or we might have only the 2nd table, and not the first. (2 x 2 = 4 possible cases here).

Above will cover all 4 cases. There is also the possible that the data set is null, and that could/would then be checked before above code...

e.g.:

```
        if (ds != null)
        {
            if (ds.Tables.Contains("Table1"))
            {
                // do whatever for table 1
            }

            if (ds.Tables.Contains("Table2"))
            {
                // do whatever for table 2
            }
        }
```